# Unmodifiable windows shortcut link : how to alter them?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

Edited the question:

When I launched and pinned SQL Data Compare to the quick launch bar, I noticed I could not run this program as an other user, using the Shift+Right click modification.

A closer inspection to the generated shortcut shows it doesn't behave as other shorctuts.

[image: Target Field is disabled and only contains app name instead of path]

In the  highlighted field, I usually get the executable file path, and I can modify it, if I want.

**Edit :** Redgate apps and *Microsoft Office 2010 apps* behave this way.

**What I tried**

- Creating a desktop shortcut directly from the executable. That worked, but that's not what I want. My desktop is already cluttered as is.
- Pinning the application on the quick launch bar gives an advertised shortcut, with no Run As option, even if I could use the run as desktop option.

**Question**

- Is there a way to create a quick launch shortcut that gives me the "Run as other user" option?
- How to disable those "advertised shortcuts"?

Comment: Looks as if it is a symbolic link, rather than a normal shortcut. You can't modify symlinks, only create or destroy them (I think). And you have to be admin. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: It is a special, so-called **advertised shortcut** which target can't be changed manually. A simple workaround could be creating a new shortcut pointing to the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not your average shortcut

It is a special, so-called **advertised shortcut** created by Windows Installer which target can't be manually changed:

> Windows Installer introduces a special type of shortcut which, while transparent to the user, contains additional metadata that Windows Installer uses through its shell integration to verify the state of the specified application's installation prior to launching the application.

If you were to [parse](http://code.google.com/p/lnk-parser/) the shortcut content, you would find a [DarwinDataBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871369.aspx) inside:

> The DarwinDataBlock structure specifies an application identifier that can be used instead of a [link target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7b5968-68f5-4e5c-8b11-00a6f4ae98ff#link_target)[IDList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7b5968-68f5-4e5c-8b11-00a6f4ae98ff#item_id_list) to install an application when a [shell link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7b5968-68f5-4e5c-8b11-00a6f4ae98ff#shell_link) is activated.

The application identifier is

> [...] an encoded representation of a specific product, component, and feature. If this extra value exists, Windows Installer will decode the data, and use it to perform checks against that product and component. If the component is found to be missing or corrupt, Windows Installer will launch a repair to restore the missing file or data, and finally launch the referenced application as normal, passing the appropriate command-line options to it.

## Solution

As per @Johan Buret's answer, use [ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361) from Sysinternals:

> From a command prompt type the following:
>
> `shellrunas.exe /reg`
>
> This will register the context menu handler.
>
> ShellRunas provides functionality similar to that of Runas to launch programs as a different user via a convenient shell context-menu entry.

## Workaround

Create a new shortcut pointing to the same application.

## References

- [[MS-SHLLINK]: Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx)
- [LNK - Forensics Wiki](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/LNK#External_Links)
- [Application Resiliency: Unlock the Hidden Features of Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302344.aspx)
- [About Windows Installer Shortcuts](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/about-windows-installer-shortcuts)
- [Run as Different User - Unavailable for Advertised shortcuts](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fc0ce9f3-169a-43c9-b878-d678745c84f0/run-as-different-user-unavailable-for-advertised-shortcuts)

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an **advertised shortcut**. Once I had the true name, I could find a solution.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fc0ce9f3-169a-43c9-b878-d678745c84f0/run-as-different-user-unavailable-for-advertised-shortcuts

> Try the ShellRunAs tool from SysInternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361
>
> From a command prompt type the following:
>
> **shellrunas.exe /reg**